# Writing empty file doesn't write file, writing too large file writes empty file

Tags: c, memcpy, fuse

I am writing file operations for a [FUSE](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/index.html) program. However I have some trouble with the `file_operations.write` function. The problem I am having is:

- Trying to write an empty file (open in vim and immediately save, so it says 0L 0C written) it doesn't write at all and leaves the contents untouched, so if the file previously contained "text" it would still contain "text".
- Trying to write a large file (about 10KB) will result in an empty file.

For the empty files part. I already tried several things, such as checking if the size is less than 1, (which I assumed to be the size given when empty files are written) and simply made the `char*` point to a single `'\0'` byte.

I also tried separate if cases and found the size to be -2 for some odd reason, however when I tried writing an empty file as explained above when -2 is found, it still didn't work.

For files too large, I have no idea.

```c
static int fs_write(const char* path, const char* buffer, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info* ffinfo) {
  // Find the associated file_t* and dir_t* to the file.
  file_t* file = get_file_from_path(path);
  dir_t* directories = get_parents_from_path(path);

  // The contents of a file are stored in a char* so I have to realloc
  // the previous pointer and memcpy the new contents from buffer to
  // file->contents, using size and offset as an indication of how large
  // to make the realloc and what to copy over.

  char* file_contents_new = (char*) realloc(file->contents, (size + 1) * sizeof(char));

    // realloc failed
    if (file_contents_new == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;

    //  point the previous file contents pointer to the newly allocated section.
    file->contents = file_contents_new;

    // Copy from buffer+offset to the file contents with the size provided.
    memcpy(file->contents, buffer + offset, size);

    *(file->contents + size) = '\0'; // Append NULL char to end file string.

    return size;
}
```

Here I expect to get proper handling for empty and large files too, because:

- size 0 (which makes most sense to me) would realloc to a char* of size 0+1 (1 for the null byte)
- then point file->contents to it
- then copy 0 bytes from buffer to file->contents
- write a `'\0'` char to the end of the file->contents (at size, which is the `length of the realloc'ed block - 1`); in this case writes `'\0'` at the 0th index.
- return the size written, in this case 0.

However, vim closes reporting it had written 0L 0C to the file, but the file was untouched.

Large files:

- the function would call write multiple times to write in chunks to the file
- However an empty file is written.

Comment: Your `realloc` call seem odd, shouldn't it be something like `realloc(file->contents, size + file->size);`?

Comment: @Mathieu I tried `realloc(file->contents, strlen(file->contents) + use_size + 1);` it didn't change anything. I assumed that `size` is the new size of buffer. Rather than append the data, it will overwrite the data. so if I wanted to write "test" into the file, it would realloc to a char* of size 4+1 to generate "test\0" basically. so I realloc just `4+1 * sizeof(char)` write "test"then append null byte.

Comment: This function overwrites the file contents with new value each time. You need to show how are you calling this function.

Answer (score 1):

I'n not use to FUSE, but I think you do not use the arguments well (see https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/passthrough.c)

- `buffer`: the data to write
- `size`: the size of buffer
- `offset`: the position to write to in file.

So your code your looks like:

```
static int fs_write(const char* path, const char* buffer, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info* ffinfo) 
{
  // Find the associated file_t* and dir_t* to the file.
  file_t* file = get_file_from_path(path);
  dir_t* directories = get_parents_from_path(path);


    /* realloc to store data. Note the +1 to store the final \0 */
    char* file_contents_new = realloc(file->contents, file->size + size+1);

    // realloc failed
    if (file_contents_new == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;


    //  point the previous file contents pointer to the newly allocated section.
    file->contents = file_contents_new;

    /* update size too, without to +1 to prevent adding one at each write call */
    file->size = file->size + size;

    // Copy buffer to the file taking offset into account
    memcpy(file->contents + offset, buffer, size);

    /* Append NULL char to end file string. */
    *(file->contents + file->size) = '\0'; 

    return size;
}
```

Comment: The problem probably has been the source that I used to figure out what 'offset' meant. They described it as `- offset: offset from where chunk should start`, I interpreted this as the offset in buffer. but it makes more sense to use the offset on the file.

Comment: However, it's still not fixed. Could it be possible that writes fail, because the read function is also wrong? Or should that not affect writing.